# Reading a text file from a batch file, then passing text to another function

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hope someone can help. I've tried by googling this site but I'm either getting the wrong keywords or else I'm the first person to come across this issue (unlikely).

I'm trying to read a list of domains from a text file in a Windows batch file, which I'll post below. For each of those I'm trying to write the results to a file. I've looked at various uses of the "for /f" but can't fathom out what I need to do to get the line to work. Here's the code:

```
@setlocal
@echo off
for /F  "tokens=1" %%D in (c:\whois-for-win32\domainlist.txt) do call :reportit
endlocal
goto :eof

:reportit
setlocal
echo " Retrieving details for:  %%D"
echo " WHOIS:       %%D" >> c:\whois-for-win32\results\domainlisting.txt
echo "=============================================================" >> c:\whois-for-win32\results\domainlisting.txt
whois %%D >> c:\whois-for-win32\results\domainlisting.txt
timeout 8
endlocal
```

Now, assume the data file referred to has only one domain listed per line. Obviously the reason I'm doing this is that we've got a rather large number of domains to check.

Your thoughts and ideas all gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use FOR-Loops the parameter is only visible in the context of the for-loop.
In your function it's not accessible as %%D.

But you could pass them with the call as parameter,
in this case I use "%%~D", as %%~D removes enclosing quotes if there are some and then i enclose it into quotes to ensure that the content will deliver as only one parameter.

In the function the passed parameter can be accessed via %1, but to remove the quotes I use %~1.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F  "tokens=* EOL=# delims=" %%D in (c:\whois-for-win32\domainlist.txt) do call :reportit "%%~D"
endlocal
goto :eof

:reportit
setlocal
set "domain=%~1"
echo " Retrieving details for:  %domain%"
echo " WHOIS:       %domain%" >> c:\whois-for-win32\results\domainlisting.txt
echo "=============================================================" >> c:\whois-for-win32\results\domainlisting.txt
whois %domain% >> c:\whois-for-win32\results\domainlisting.txt
timeout 8
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: Not sure if it's anything to do with the fact that this is Windows 7 but even this is not working for me, jeb. Thank you for clarifying the matter regarding passing %%D to a subroutine, as it had slipped my mind about that issue.<br/> I tried just running "for /f "tokens=1" %%D in (c:\whois-for-win32\domainlist.txt) do echo %%D" which resulted in absolutely nothing, so I figured there was something wrong with the file. I then tried "more domainlist.txt" and got a domain per line, undelimited (is that relevant?), so now it seems as though the problem is in the for [...] do loop. Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes, if your lines begins with the EOL character `;` than they will be ignored, try to use `"tokens=* eol=# delims="`

Comment: Tried that, not that any of the text file contains a single EOL or ; characted (or any special characters - CR/LF excluded). Still not reading the file from appearances...

Comment: What do you get for `for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%D in (yourFile.txt) do echo %%D` ?

Comment: @MarcusWebb1966: What encoding does the file use? More specifically, is it ANSI or Unicode?

Comment: @Jeb - %%D was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @AndriyM - AhA! It was in Little Endian for some unfathomable reason - changing it to ANSI made it work 
Jeb - changed to ANSI and removed second % I can now output the datafile line by line as per expectations!